# Javascript undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

anytime I'm trying to reference my global variable i get an `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` error and nothing happens. I'm probably missing something obvious since I'm new to javascript. 
I've simplified the code below so that you can give it a look. All help is much appreciated.

```
var popup;

function first(){
    popup = window.open(...); //opens a popup
    popup.moveTo(10,10) //moves the window
    second();
}

function second(){
    .
    .
    .
    //does an XMLHttpRequest and when it's done (simplified) it tries to close the window
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        popup.close();
    }
}
```

Whenever popup.close() is fired I get the error above. Am I missing something really obvious here?

For future problems as this, here is a solution:

instead of `popup.close();`

```
var win = window.open("","popup");//open a new window with the same name as before
win.close();
```

By doing so it will reference the same window object and will be able to close it.

Comment: You dont have function `close` in the `pop` object

Comment: You're calling second before you're calling first.

Comment: I suspect the same as @BenjaminGruenbaum. But you could easily avoid such mistakes by defining `popup` inside `first` and passing it to `second` as argument.

Comment: @user2071225 I see what you're thinking but first(); has to run when I want it to and not on startup.. Shouldn't it be a global reference?

Comment: @user2970038 You need to post how you call these functions if you want to get this solved. Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @jgillich I might have simplified it too much but I'll create a JSFiddle, hang on

Comment: @jgillich and others, here's the code not so simplified [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6Eh4f/)

Answer (score 2):

From your error, there is two possibility

1. `pop` is not accessible
2. `close` does not exist in `pop` object

I tried both in console

**When object `pop` does not exist**

```
  pop.close()
```

Error you will get

```
  ReferenceError: pop is not defined
```

**When no function `close` in the object**

```
 var pop = {}
 pop.close()
```

Error you will get

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

From your error, there is no function name `close` in the pop object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
var popup;

function first(){
    popup = window.open(...); //opens a popup
    popup.moveTo(10,10) //moves the window
    second(popup);
}

function second(popup_){
    .
    .
    .
    //does an XMLHttpRequest and when it's done (simplified) it tries to close the window
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        popup_.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's giving me the same error which is weird since popup.moveTo works :/